# Pascal's law - pressure in other parts of the container

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, continuum-mechanics

Throughout this question I'm assuming an idealised scenario, working with an incompressible fluid and no other forces than those explicitly mentioned.

Pascal's law often gives the example of a U-shaped tube, with two pistons. It's then reasoned that pressing on the left piston will result in an equal amount of pressure being applied on the right piston.

1, What about other parts of the container, i.e. the tube itself? I'd assume the pressure there will be the same too, because technically we could still imagine the tubes are "pistons" too (there just happens to be some force that keeps them from moving), but it's not explicitly stated anywhere, and I'm not really sure.

2, What about the left piston itself? Will the liquid inside actually apply an opposite pressure on it too? Assuming both the pistons are of same area, I'd guess things will end up moving, meaning the total force applied is not zero. Assuming both the pistons move with the same velocity, it would make sense that the there is no opposite force on the left piston itself. Is this the case? If not, how come?

//

I think the (2) above is wrong, and it's simply one of those paradoxical situations where you can't apply a law that's meant to be used in some "static" way, to the actual behavior that happens? It seems much more intuitive and consistent that the pressure will be the same everywhere.

In an alternative scenario where there is no "right" piston, i.e. we are simply trying to compress a fluid, it's much more reasonable to think that there will simply be an opposite pressure everywhere, even against the piston we are pressing.

Maybe it could be said that while at the moment of applying force, there will be an opposite pressure on the piston, once the right piston moves, then because the fluid is incompressible, it will "pull" the whole liquid towards the direction of the right piston? I don't know.